# Where can I find a good perl script for a cronjob that backs up all files in a specific folder on my webspace?

Tags: perl, ftp, automation, cron

I want to automate backups on my webspace. My provider allows for cronjobs to be executed once a day. I have already implemented a cronjob that backs up my database with mySQLdumper, using a perl script. Now I want to use a script that backs up all my files in a specific folder (e.g. /folder/), zips them and moves them to /backups/

Is there a way to do so? If yes, could you recommend a good perl script template that lets me easily modify it so I can use it the way I want? Ideally, it would also have the feature to exclude certain file types, like jpg, gif and png.

Comment: Have you tried anything or even searched Google or this site?  This is a very well-covered topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tar:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html

Basically create a new archive, with compression enabled (zlib or bzip2).

Archive::Tar->create_archive($file, $compressed, @filelist)

Add files using:

$tar->add_files( @filenamelist )
or
$tar->add_data ( $filename, $data, [$opthashref] )

Its probably easier and faster to use /bin/tar, as tar has --exclude options.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar